# How Do You Use Media Queria to Hide a Column from Display Grid and Adjust Your Spacing in the Column that Remains?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I'm working with CSS grids for the first time, and am kind of amazed at what they can do.  I'm especially loving the fr unit.  I have encountered an issue that is giving me fits however.

What I want to do is combine CSS grid and media query so that when the viewport reaches a certain size that the second column is no longer displayed. Check.  That part is done.  The part I can't quite figure out how to accomplish however is this:

I want the text that I have told to be center aligned to be center aligned across the row after the other column is removed.  As it stands now, it holds the position it was in when the other column was present.

Also column 2 had a fixed height, but when the column is hidden with media query, the height of the remaining column is now smaller. It doesn't even stay tall enough to hold all of it's original content.  I am able to partially fix that by assigning both columns the same explicit height or min-height, but strangely when I do that the vertical alignment of the column is no longer centered and moves to the top of the container.

```css
/* - Code Requested by Commenter - */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

h1 {font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif}

h2 {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}

body,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}

.pagecontainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-container {
    width: 100%
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 72px;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 16px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-right {
    float: right!important;
}

.navlogo {
    width: auto;
    height: 72px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar .navbar-item {
    padding: 0 16px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-block .navbar-item {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    white-space: normal;
    float: none;
    outline: 0;
}

/* common styles used throughout */
.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.big-text {
    font-size: 20px!important;
}

.huge-text {
    font-size: 64px!important;
}

/* Full height header */
.header {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(0, 0, 45, .92), rgba(45, 0, 0, 0.66)), url("../images/headerImage.jpg");
    min-height: 90vh;
}

.header-display-left {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0%;
    padding: 50px;
    transform:translate(0%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-0%,-50%)
}

.header-white-text {
    color: #fff;
}

.h1-header {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 0.2;
}

.h2-header {
    font-size: 28px;
}

.header-description {
    max-width: 584px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.9;
}

.header-description a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:rgba(205, 0, 0, .6);
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border-radius: 11px;
}

.header-description a:hover {
    background-color:rgb(205, 0, 0);
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border-radius: 11px;
}

.header-display-bottomleft {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.header-fa {
    font-size:20px!important;
    color: #888!important;
    padding: 0px 0px 48px 48px;
}

.header-fa a {
    font-size:20px!important;
    color: #888!important;
    padding: 0px 0px 48px 0;
}

.fa-hover:hover {
    color: #eee;
}

.fa-hover a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}

.about-container {
    padding: 80px 40px;
}

/* row stylings */

.max-4-cols {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-column-gap: 28px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    align-items: center;
  }

/* - All Code Above Requested by Commenter - */
.split-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #420000;
    height: 460px;
}

.leftsplit {
    color: #fff!important;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.rightsplit {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../images/berries.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.services-text {
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8);
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
  
/* - Requested Media Queries - */
/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .hide-mobile {
        display: none!important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .hide-desktop {
        display: none!important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .rightsplit {
        display: none!important;
    }

    .split-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="split-container" id="services">
      <div class="column leftsplit center-text">
        <h2 class="services-text">Our Services</h2>
        <p class="services-description big-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Service 1</p>
        <p class="services-description big-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Service 2</p>
        <p class="services-description big-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Service 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column rightsplit"></div>
  </div>
```

[See What Happens When I Resize Here](https://youtu.be/M-F0amh0y3s)

Comment: Hello! Can you please add the media queries and the rest of the CSS as well?

Comment: What I'm assuming is happening is you use media query to hide a column when a certain threshold is reached, but at that same threshold you should also change the rule of the first column to take up the whole row - I'm assuming it still has it's old rule about taking half of space.

Comment: @Mahatmasamatman It appears you were right.  I changed the media query to alter my .split-container to having only a "1fr" grid-template-columns.  That did take care of the centering issue.  The container still doesn't stay tall enough to hold the content however, and when i set the height of .leftsplit to 460px, all text moves up and loses the vertical alignment.

Comment: I decided to set the height of split-container to the 460px and changed the height of leftsplit and rightsplit to 100% with relative positioning.  It didn't make anything better, but it didn't make anything worse.  That's sort of what I was going for while I try to work this out.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I can't figure out what exactly is going on with the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

At the same time you hide your right column, you should reset the grid, so the remaining column takes the whole row.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .rightsplit {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .split-container{
       grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was replying to you in my OP while you were supplying that code.  I had just tried that while you were typing.  It does take care of the horizontal centering issue, but seems to create a vertical-centering one.

Answer (score 0):

The media query was solved by resetting .split-container as @Mahatmasamatman suggested.  The vertical spacing issue was fixed by assigning an explicit height to the grid container ".split-container" and then giving my left column div (.leftsplit) a height of 140px with a margin of 0 and relative positioning.  I then put my .services-text to a margin of auto with a margin-bottom of -5px. Lastly, I set the margin for .services-description to auto.  It was a lot of work, but I think I achieved what I was after.

```css
.split-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #420000;
    height: 460px;
    text-align: center;
}

.leftsplit {
    color: #fff!important;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative; 
    height: 140px;
    display: grid;
}

.rightsplit {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url("../images/berries.jpg");
    height: 100%;
}

.services-text {
    font-size: 42px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.services-description {
    margin: auto;
}

/* Media Query */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .rightsplit {
        display: none!important;
    }

    .split-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="split-container" id="services">
      <div class="column leftsplit center-text">
        <h2 class="services-text">Our Services</h2>
        <p class="services-description big-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Service 1</p>
        <p class="services-description big-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Service 2</p>
        <p class="services-description big-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Service 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column rightsplit"></div>
  </div>
```